# Plotting data from Queue in process

Tags: python, plot, process, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to have two processes running – one delivering data via Queue() and the other reading out the queue and plotting it simultaneously. The code works without errors, except that the plot isn't showing. Only the empty figure appears after both processes are done.

I hope that anyone can find the problem in my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

def worker():
    for i in range(20):
        q.put(random.random())
        t.put(random.random())
        # time.sleep(0.01)
        
    
def plotter(q,t):
    while not q.empty():
        x = q.get()
        y = t.get()
        
        print(x,y)
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        # plt.show()
        time.sleep((0.1))

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    t = mp.Queue()
    r = mp.Process(target = plotter, args = (q,t))
    p = mp.Process(target = worker)
    p.start()
    r.start()
    p.join()
    r.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it running with changing the plotter method like so:

```py
def plotter(q, t):
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    while not q.empty():
        x = q.get()
        y = t.get()

        print(x, y)
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        time.sleep((0.1))
    plt.show()
```

I moved the `plt.figure` into the method, because it was not shared between the processes. It was only executed in the main process, not `r`.

At the first run, I had to put a `time.sleep()` between the process starts. Otherwise there was nothing in the queue and the `plotter` immediatly finished.

And of course, put the `plt.show()` outside the loop.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer! I've tried out your solution and I've got an error (it displays multiple times in the console): __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug. Have you got an idea what could cause this?

Comment: I could debug this error by changing the graphic preferences to 'inline' instead of 'Qt5'. Now I've only got one problem left: How can I change the plotter() method so that every point is added in real-time to the plot? And display the plot not 'inline'?